# Why don't the Rattay soldiers like me?

Tags: kingdom-come-deliverance

I have been steadily improving my reputation with the various groups in Rattay. However my reputation with the soldiers keeps on dropping and is now down to 10.

What impacts the relationship with soldiers and how can I improve it?

Comment: Doing the bandit camp side quest for Bernand will improve the reputation to max.

Answer (score 2):

Some have suggested that there isn't much you can do. Caving in to their demands when they want to search you helps, also keep talking to them and exhausting every dialogue options.

Of course breaking the law will drop it so try to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Going to a church and tipping Groschen to buy indulgences is said to improve reputation, but I've never quite understood how/how much.

It may be worth a try, although it seems to be increasingly costly (it currently costs me 1851 Groschens per buy...).

Also, serving jail time is said to improve your reputation, but maybe only if it's negative.